# Return address function causing issues

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm writing a program in **C** and setting up a struct to be used inside another struct like so:

`typedef VOID(WINAPI* OriginalFunc)(PVOID);`

```
struct C_Child
{
    
    VOID GetName( )
    {
        return ((OriginalFunc*)(this))[0x0000](this);
    }
};
```

Then:

```
struct C_Parent
{
    struct C_Child* Child;
} Parent;
```

However, when I call my struct like so:

`Parent.Child->GetName();`

To access the "GetName" function inside of my child class from the parent, I always end up not being able to compile, and I'm given numerous syntax errors.

**Example 1:** [image]

**Example 2:** [image]

> Before I get heckled too hard, I'll just notify everyone here that I predominately work in C++, and I've done this numerous times before using it-- I know the languages are different, but I'm seriously just confused as to why this is causing such a problem.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can correct this, or possibly achieve the same result a different way?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't define functions (such as `GetName()`) inside a structure in C.  C doesn't provide the grouping of code and data that C++ does.

Comment: Dang. Yeah, I had some assumptions, but I didn't think that it was a result of how the language handled it. Thanks, @JonathanLeffler!

Comment: Please: the error in *text* (copy-paste), not as a screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```c
VOID WINAPI C_Child_GetName(PVOID a) {
  // ...
}

struct C_Child {
   OriginalFunc GetName;
} Child = {
   .GetName = C_Child_GetName,
};

struct C_Parent {
   struct C_Child *Child;
} Parent = {
   .Child = &Child,
};
```

This allows one to do the requested

```c
Parent.Child->GetName();
```

Tested using

```c
typedef void VOID;
typedef void *PVOID;
#define WINAPI
typedef VOID (WINAPI *OriginalFunc)(PVOID);
```

Comment: Sadly, Jon was right about my issue. This looks really good, but apparently the language can't handle the grouping indexes which C++ can. : (

Comment: You already knew the syntax you wanted wasn't allowed. I provided the correct syntax to achieve what you wanted to do (`Parent.Child->GetName();`)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you want to do :(

You cannot have a function inside the struct but you can write code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef void* (*pFV)(void*);

typedef struct 
{
    pFV         name[4];
}   C_Child;


typedef struct
{
    C_Child*    Child;
}   Parent;

void* GetName(void* v)
{
    printf("GetName()\n");
    return v;
}

int main(void)
{
    Parent   parent;
    C_Child  child;

    child.name[0] = GetName;
    parent.Child = &child;
    (parent.Child->name[0])(NULL);
}
```

And load function addresses inside the child class. This is a common construct, like a Virtual Function Table, and is frequent in Windows and other systems

This line

```
        (parent.Child->name[0])(NULL);
```

calls the function `GetName()` as expected.

It it what you want?